# Diagonal symmetry across a filtered array?

Tags: java, libgdx, procedural-generation, grid, filtering

I wrote this code to randomly generate a square terrain that somewhat resembles an island. First, I randomly populated a square with grass tiles (1s) on a plane of water tiles (0s):

[image]

Then, I looped through each tile and changed its tile type according to its neighboring tiles(if a tile is surrounded by 4 or more water tiles, it becomes a water tile, otherwise it becomes a grass tile):

[image]

The results don't seem all that pleasing; not only is the terrain filled with holes and lack overall "togetherness", it is also weirdly symmetrical diagonally.

Here's the code:

```
private void SmoothMap (Chunk chunk)
{
    for(int row = 1; row < chunk.rows-1; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 1; col < chunk.cols-1; col++)
        {
            //if current tile is not null
            if(chunk.GetTile(row, col) != null)
            {
                //Check its neighboring tiles
                int neighboringTiles = GetSurroundingTiles(row, col, chunk);
                //System.out.println("Position: " + row + ", " + col);
                //System.out.println("Current tile type: " + chunk.GetTile(row, col).type);
                //System.out.println("Neighboring water tiles: " + neighboringTiles);

                if (neighboringTiles > 4)
                {
                    if (chunk.GetTile(row, col) != null)
                    {
                        chunk.GetTile(row, col).texture = GetRandomWaterTexture();
                        chunk.GetTile(row, col).type = Enums.tileType.Water;
                    }
                }
                else if (neighboringTiles < 4)
                {
                    if (chunk.GetTile(row, col) != null)
                    {
                        chunk.GetTile(row, col).texture = GetRandomGrassTexture();
                        chunk.GetTile(row, col).type = Enums.tileType.Grass;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private int GetSurroundingTiles(int r, int c, Chunk chunk)
{
    int surroundingTiles = 0;

    for(int x = c-1; x <= c+1; x++)
    {
        for(int y = r-1; y <= r+1; y++)
        {
            if (x != c || y != r)
            {
                if(chunk.GetTile(x, y) != null)
                {
                    if (chunk.GetTileCode(x, y).equals("0"))
                    {
                        surroundingTiles++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return surroundingTiles;
}
```

Does anyone know why it is the way it is? Or a better way to approach generating an terrain like this?

Here's the GetTile() code:

```
public String GetTileCode(int r, int c)
{
    Tile tile;
    ArrayList<Tile> chunk_row;
    if(tiles.size() > r && r >= 0){
        chunk_row = tiles.get(r);

        if(chunk_row != null && chunk_row.size() > c && c >= 0){
            tile = chunk_row.get(c);
            return tile.isGrass() ? "1" : "0";
        }
    }
    return "0";
}
```

1 is grass, and 0 is water.

Comment: after calling the SmoothMap method 4 times, the terrain looked a bit better; however it is obviously symmetrical (something I want to avoid in a randomly generated terrain).

Comment: Can we see your `chunk.GetTileCode()`?

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer the question is now updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing to the same array you are reading from - that's what causes diagonal symmetry. Problem is you can't sample correctly if you have already begun to change the array you are sampling from! You must have a copy of the tiles array in order to avoid this. Write into a fresh/clear array, then copy contents over from it after you are finished smoothing. Here is code that works:

```
public struct Tile //struct allows copy. We need this for copying to and fro from tiles to tilesSmoothed. 
{
    public bool isLand;
    public string somethingElse;
}

public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const int ROWS = 50;
    public const int COLS = 50;

    Tile[,] tiles = new Tile[COLS, ROWS];
    Tile[,] tilesSmoothed = new Tile[COLS, ROWS];
    GameObject[,] tileGOs = new GameObject[COLS, ROWS]; 

    void Start ()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < COLS; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++)
            {
                //data model
                tiles[x,y] = new Tile();
                tiles[x,y].isLand = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f) >= 0.5f ? true : false;

                //tilesSmoothed[x,y] = new Tile(); //unnecessary - all structs are initialised to zero / false

                //view
                tileGOs[x,y] = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                tileGOs[x,y].transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
                tileGOs[x,y].SetActive(tiles[x,y].isLand);
            }
        }
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            SmoothMap();
        }
    }

    private void SmoothMap()
    {
        //1st loop populates tilesSmoothed
        for (int x = 1; x < COLS-1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y < ROWS-1; y++)
            {
                //if current tile is not null
                if (tiles[x,y].isLand)
                {
                    //Check its neighboring tiles
                    int neighbourCount = CountNeighbourTiles(x, y);
                    tilesSmoothed[x,y].isLand = neighbourCount > 4;
                }
            }
        }

        //2nd loop copies those results from tilesSmoothed into tiles
        for (int x = 0; x < COLS; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++)
            {
                //model
                tiles[x,y].isLand = tilesSmoothed[x,y].isLand; //COPY!
                //remember to also clear tilesSmoothed[x,y] here if you like, but for now this is not req'd.

                //view
                tileGOs[x,y].SetActive(tiles[x,y].isLand);
            }
        }
    }

    private int CountNeighbourTiles(int x, int y)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (int nx = x-1; nx < x+1+1; nx++)
        {
            for (int ny = y-1; ny < y+1+1; ny++)
            {
                //if (x != c || y != r) //this is not required and is costly - see return line below
                //{
                if (tiles[nx,ny].isLand)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                //}
            }
        }
        return count - 1; //you can assume -1 since the current tile must be valid and was definitely counted
    }
}
```

As for your approach to smoothing...

`SmoothMap` should probably handle cases where e.g. we are surrounded by 3 tiles (checking horizontally and vertically, the count goes up to 4; checking diagonally, the number can go up to 8). You can either count the total surrounding valid tiles and act accordingly, or act on them according to structure, such as look at who is adjacent to who, e.g. 2 in the top right and 3 in the bottom left - neither group touching the other. None of this is essential to solving your main problem which is symmetry, but it will help with smoothing if implemented well. I've changed your `GetSurroundingTiles` to be subtly more efficient.

What you're doing here is a 3x3 box filter which is a sound and common approach. For a smoother map, you must increase the resolution of the grid, i.e. increase the values of `ROWS` & `COLS`.

**As a lesson to take from this, remember always to reduce your code down to the most basic thing that works, in order to solve mind-numbing problems.**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will post updates when I figure something out.

Comment: @Harrylujah Feel free to post any further queries here.

Comment: I cleaned up my coded a little bit and got rid of the ArrayList within an ArrayList implementation for storing tiles. I'm now using a more straightforward Tile[][] for simpler reading and writing tiles, but I'm still getting the exact same results...

Comment: as for SmoothMap(), I loop through every tile excluding the edges to determine its neighboring edges, and I check every tile surrounding the current tile including diagonals... I'm not sure what you mean by the example you've given.

Comment: @Harrylujah Have you begun logging out the indices? You have to do this to find the problem. First, do us a favour: Run `SmoothMap` once, then twice, then thrice, and tell me if it becomes _more symmetrical_ each time. This is very important. I know at the moment you are doing it 4x.

Comment: I logged out individual indices and I can't seem to find any irregularities; it loops every single tile in order as it should. And yes, the map does get increasingly symmetrical if I run `SmoothMap()` more than once.

Comment: The example in the question is not a very good one; the terrain does not necessarily become more symmetrical, it just becomes more defined as more loose pieces are smoothed out.

Comment: @Harrylujah Except I'm looking at that original map and there is almost no symmetry in it. Which implies the symmetry only appears gradually during the smoothing process. Which implies that your smoothing algorithm is sampling at the wrong indices. So question is fine :)

Comment: Oops, the first picture is before any smoothing is done :) The tile placement is completely random before smoothing.

Comment: @Harrylujah Correct. That's what I was relying on. That is good. There is nothing wrong with the question and it has helped me deduce the general flavour of your problem. Anyway, I'm drafting a quick sample in Unity that should work.

Comment: @Harrylujah I remembered what it is. Thank you for helping me to remember, I've been trying to remember for ages what causes this problem: You are writing to the same array you are reading from - that's what causes the diagonal line. You must have a copy of the tiles array in order to avoid this.

Comment: @Harrylujah Working code supplied. Just put it in a script called Main and drop it on the Camera (for instance). Move your camera to (50,50,-100). Run, press space to smooth.

Comment: The symmetry is gone(hooray!)... however, the terrain is far from smooth. Sorry to repeat the question, but do you mind explaining your suggestion for `SmoothMap()`?

Comment: @Harrylujah If you want it smoothER, increase the grid resolution (i.e. increase `ROWS` & `COLS`). You can also play with the value 4 (let's call it `threshold`): if you reduce it, you will be left with more islands at each stage. For any problems beyond this, I suggest you open a new question, as I've solved your primary issue which was symmetry. Smoothing is an entirely different topic with many ways to solve.